# Why this query that retrieve records having a DateTime field equals to a specified value is not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime, rdbms

I am working with **MySql** and I am finding some difficulties trying to check if a **DateTime** field is equal to a specified value.

Into my database I have a **MeteoForecast** table containing a **DateTime** field named **start_date** that hold value like this: **05/03/2018 12:00:00**

Ok, then I implement this query that check if in the table exists records having a start date value subsequent to the date represented by a specified value, this is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM MeteoForecast          AS MF
WHERE 
     MF.localization_id = 1
AND
     MF.start_date >= '05/03/2018 12:00:00'
```

It seems works except the fact that the result is excluding the record having the **start_date** field equals to the value specified in my WHERE clause.

Ok, but I need to retrieve the record having the **start_date** field that holds exactly the value specified in my WHERE clause, so I tried to do in this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM MeteoForecast          AS MF
WHERE 
     MF.localization_id = 1
AND
     MF.start_date = '05/03/2018 12:00:00'
```

It return an empyt result set.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this query?

Answer (score 0):

Use standard date formats. Assuming you want March 5, 2018:

```
WHERE MF.localization_id = 1 AND
      MF.start_date = '2018-03-05 12:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your date format from '05/03/2018 12:00:00' to '2018-03-05 12:00:00'

```
SELECT *
FROM MeteoForecast AS MF
WHERE MF.localization_id = 1
AND MF.start_date = '2018-03-05 12:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be related to fractional part of datetime.

Many systems stores datimes as float numbers with integer part related to days since a specific date and fractional part related to fraction of the day (so 0.5 is 12:00:00)

The main problem is that the fractional part often stores also milliseconds (or even microseconds) and when you save your date to the database your value is approximated to the nearest float value supported (this happens also when you load it from the database in your application).

So you can't simply test `MyColumn.Date = '01/01/2018 12:00:00'` because your column value could be `'01/01/2018 11:59:59.999999'` or `'01/01/2018 12:00:00.000001'`

In these cases it could be quite difficult to test for a datetime equality because of this problem.

So you have to check first your `start_date` column dataype if it is DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, check also if after the datatype is specified a precision number like `DATETIME(6)`

Try this and let me know:

```
SELECT *
FROM MeteoForecast AS MF
WHERE MF.localization_id = 1
AND cast(MF.start_date as datetime) = '2018-03-05 12:00:00'
```